# Building features for Intrusion Detection System using JPCAP

Tags: sniffer, intrusion-detection

I am doing project on intrusion detection system. I am using JPCAP library to capture packet. Using JPCAP I am able to construct basic features of TCP Connections mentioned in KDD 99 dataset(e.g. Duration, protocol_type, Service, Source port, destination port). I want to construct content features like "**hot indicators, num_failed_logins, su_attempted, is_hot_login, is_guest_login"**. And time based features like "**count, serror_rate,rerror_rate, same service rate**".

So please give me any hint about constructing such features from live traffic.

Comment: Isn't the KDD99 dataset no longer recommended for use?

Comment: I'm guessing this is another student in the same class as the previous two or three people we had constantly asking about KDD99 on Security.SE

Answer (score 1):

The features you have implemented are just network level features i.e. time Duration, protocol_type, Service, Source port, destination port which you can get by reading IP packets using JPCAP. The problem is that JPCAP/Libpcap is just a sniffer library and does not handle low-level protocol issues. For handling all TCP/IP stuff like

1. IP fragmentation
2. TCP Retransmission
3. Packet Reordering

I recommend integration of your code with [Libnids](http://libnids.sourceforge.net/) which emulates the IP stack of Linux 2.0.x. and provides IP defragmentation, TCP stream assembly and review [Justniffer](http://justniffer.sourceforge.net/) as an implementation.